# Get newest created custom category (get_term_by and variables) (outside Loop)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am wondering if there is any reason why the following code would not work?

My situation: I have a custom category set up called 'Issue'. What I want to do is get the most newly created category (which is 'Volume 2 Issue 1') and get its ID so that I can run the [plugin](http://zahlan.net/blog/2012/06/categories-images/) function `z_taxonomy_image_url($currentID);` which outputs a URL based on the category identified by `$currentID`

I have a very hacky solution at the moment, but if anyone can figure out why the last 3 lines of the following bit of code doesn't work, it would be fantastic.

Alternative and cleaner solutions would also be appreciated.

```
$taxonomy=wp_list_categories('taxonomy=issue&echo=0&number=1&orderby=ID&order=DESC&show_count=0&style=none&title_li=');
$tax = strip_tags($taxonomy);
$newtax = "'".trim($tax)."'";
$getID = get_term_by('name', $newtax, 'issue');
$currentID = $getID->term_id;
```

Doing a `var_dump` on `$getID` only results in `bool(false)`

The interesting thing is that this code works (but I cannot use it because it would require manually changing the code each time I create a new category).

```
$getID = get_term_by('name', 'Volume 2 Issue 1', 'issue');
$currentID = $getID->term_id;
```

Is there something with `get_term_by` that it rejects using `$newtax` but accepts `'Volume 2 Issue 1'` ? If yes, is there a workaround or do I need to look for some other way of doing this?

I am not very well versed in PHP and WP codes. I am not afraid of tinkering, but my knowledge is only basics :( Please bear with me.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just a hint: _Not_ using query string syntax, but an array instead will make it much easier to debug in the future. Also query string syntax is deprecated and will be remove in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the single quotes I had been adding to `$newtax` got it to work (as following:)

```
$taxonomy=wp_list_categories('taxonomy=issue&echo=0&number=1&orderby=ID&order=DESC&show_count=0&style=none&title_li=');
$tax = strip_tags($taxonomy);
$newtax = trim($tax);
$getID = get_term_by('name', $newtax, 'issue');
$currentID = $getID->term_id;
```

For this, the matter is presently solved.

However, if anyone can propose a better/cleaner solution, that would be excellent.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

The parameters passed are basically the same except it returns an object containing all the category information. Using this function can replace the first 4 lines of your code. Now your final code becomes:

```
$getID = get_categories('taxonomy=issue&number=1&orderby=ID&order=DESC');
$currentID = $getID->term_id;
```

Comment: Gave it a shot but it wouldn't display the URL so I did a `var_dump` on `$currentID` and it output `NULL`

Comment: are you sure there is a term in the database matching the get_categories criteria? Acc. to the codex at the provided link, it should be working

Comment: Yup. Under the 'Issue' taxonomy are: Volume 1 Issue 1, Volume 1 Issue 2, Volume 1 Issue 3, and Volume 2 Issue 1. I posted an answer below how removing the apostrophes from the third line solved the problem.